# How to change keyborad's foucs color on Xbox?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, xbox, xbox-one

I'm developing an uwp app on Xbox.
When the focus is on a `TextBox`, the keyboard will popup.
Button the focus color on keyboard in always green, default color.

So is there any way to change the Focus color?
I didn't find any docs on google.

[image]

Comment: No, you can't change it programmatically in your app.

Comment: OK, Got it. But I still want MS can give us api, the default is conflict with our app theme color.

Comment: You could open a feature request in the Feedback Hub about this. You could invite others to vote up the request so that it will be easier to be noticed by the dev team.

Comment: Seems useless. I posted many features/bugs of uwp controls, but the dev team did not notice. But the bugs are really existed.

Comment: The more votes up one request have, the easier the request will be noticed. You could let others vote the request up.